# EF 4.1 : Bad reading (query result mixed/merged from database and in memory values)

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity for example which has a foreign key to another entity:

```
public entityA
{
   ....
        [ForeignKey("State")]
        public virtual int StateId { get; set; }
        public virtual States State { get; set; }
   ....
}

IDbSet<entityA> EntitiesA;
```

StateId is initially initialized to 10 by default.

I initialize my context to database and I use always the same. Once initialized with using clause I do some changes on some entities in EntitiesA collection (that is setting StateId to 20) but I do not commit changes to database using context.SaveChanges() because I do not want at this point.

After modifying some entities I reach to a point in my app that I do the following:

```
IQueryable<EntityA> entities = 
                context.EntitiesA.Where(e => e.StateId == 10);
foreach (EntityA _currentEntity in entities)
{
  ....
}
```

At this point, as I have not perfomed savechanges to database, entities in database continues having its state to 10 (not to the modified 20) so condition e.StateId == 10 is satisfied but entities is containing items whose StateId is 20 so I do not understand this....

The desired behaviour would be that condition e.StateId not being satisfied for those that has been modified previously to 20 and entities only containing those items whose stateid is still 10 (not modified).

Any ideas? It seems like query is launched against database and the results in fact are taken from in memory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is expected but yes, it is confusing. In order to fix the problem you have to run a weird looking query like this for example:

```
IEnumerable<EntityA> entities = context.EntitiesA
    .Where(e => e.StateId == 10)  // LINQ-to-Entities = filter in database
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(e => e.StateId == 10); // LINQ-to-Objects = filter in memory

foreach (EntityA _currentEntity in entities)
{
    ....
}
```

What happens is that your query retrieves entities with `StateId` = 10 in the database. When the result is returned EF runs through all loaded rows and checks if an entity that has the same key is already attached to the context.

- If yes, it returns this attached entity in the enumeration with all the values that it currently has in memory. EF does not update the values from the loaded row by default, so that the `StateId` of your modified entities is still `20`.
- If no, it attaches the new entity (that has `StateId` 10) to the context and returns it as part of the enumeration.

As a result you get this mix of entities that have `StateId` 10 or 20. Basically your query means: "Give me all entities that have a `StateId` of `10` **in the database**."

By appending `.AsEnumerable().Where(e => e.StateId == 10)` to the query you filter out the entities that have a `StateId` of `10` **in memory**.

Comment: I think EF behaviour sometimes is a little bit confusing. The normal EF behaviour, from my point of view, should be: "do not mix/merge results automatically from database and in memory unless that I explicitly tell you". So if I launch query against database, only database values should be returned and If I launch query against in memory only in memory values should be returned. EF behaviour sometimes is a surprise... Thanks for your detailed explanation. It helped me a lot to understand EF behaviour.